# Do we need do to IP warming for additional dedicated IP we bought outside of SAP

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package, ip-warming

Hi everyone seeking your advise on the following - we have bought additional dedicated IP apart from the IP we get with SAP to solely dedicate it for transactional sends. Can you please let me know if we need to do IP warming for this additional dedicated IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tl;dr: Yes.

Why:

- One main point for a dedicated IP is to control your own sender reputations at the various email providers like gmail, yahoo.
- A new IP is cold, i.e. has no reputation anywhere.
- The point of IP warming is to establish a positive sender reputation.
- Negative / No reputation will be more likely to be blocked in case an e-mail provider notices a sudden spike in volume.
- I understand you are sending transactional e-mails, which probably do not create the same "spikes" like a bulk sendout would, but you'd anyway not start blasting a million emails a day, even if those are individual sendouts.
- Set up a transition where you slowly increase the share of e-mails sent from the new setup ("test the waters", in a sense). Especially where you are not sure, you want to be careful and have a contingency plan, especially for transactional emails. What if you ARE indeed blocked by one provider but those e-mails need to reach the audience -> definitely you want to have your old setup as a fall-back in case of interruptions until you have everything stabilized.
- Many e-mail providers look at your IP for reputation, some consider the domain more. That is totally up to them, so you cannot say hard and fast where to expect what. I've seen deliverability people ditch the term "IP warming" in favor of the more generic "warming", but that doesn't mean you can forget about IP, instead that you should also be careful about domain.

While domain-based reputation could "carry over" onto sending with same domain but a new IP,  the effect of using a cold IP would most likely be noticeable in negative deliverability. Hence: yes, you should warm it up.

There are ample resources on the web;
e,g, returnpath / now validity, sendGrid.

https://help.returnpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/222437627-How-to-warm-up-an-IP-address

https://sendgrid.com/blog/how-to-warm-up-an-ip-address-how-much-and-when/

Comment: Thanks once again @Jonas, SF support came back with a yes too, but definitely your detailed answer makes more sense to me and how i move forward with my IP warming strategy. TA